# Сделать переменные с учётом MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Таблица]
Так же используется мой старый код с MySql на php:

```
$rows = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY time ASC");
        while($row = $rows->fetch_assoc()){
          echo "
            <td>".$row['donate']."</td>
            <td>".$row['nickname']."</td>
            <td>".$row['command']."</td>
            <td>".$row['intid']."</td>
            <td>".$row['amount']."</td>
            <td>".$row['status']."</td>
            <td>".date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $row['time'])."</td>
          </tr>";
        }
```

В предпоследнем столбце status есть 2 значения:
Это 0 - неудача, и 1 - удача. Как видно на фотографии, пишется 0. Нужно чтобы сразу это значение заменялось на Удачно или Неудачно. Можете помочь с кодом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пример։

```
 $rows = $mysqli->query( "SELECT * FROM `data` ORDER BY time ASC" );
 while ( $row = $rows->fetch_assoc() ) {

    $status = ( $row[ 'status' ] == 1 ? 'Удачно' : 'Неудачно' );

       echo "
        <td>" . $row[ 'donate' ] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row[ 'nickname' ] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row[ 'command' ] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row[ 'intid' ] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row[ 'amount' ] . "</td>
        <td>" . $status . "</td>
        <td>" . date( 'd-m-Y H:i:s', $row[ 'time' ] ) . "</td>
      </tr>";
}
```

Comment: От всей души, благодарю